# Illegal hardware instruction on a c program compiled on Mac

Tags: c++

I am getting an `illegal hardware instruction` error when compiled on mac. Appreciate any pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
int * fun(int * x)
{
    return  x;
}
int main()
{
    int * x;
    *x=10;
    cout << fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `int * x;` to `int xx; int * x = &xx;` and Bob's your uncle.  *Appreciate any pointers.*  See what I did there?  I gave you a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are just pointers. In your code there is no integer that you could assign a value to.

This

```
int * x;
```

Declares `x` to be a pointer to `int`. It is uninitialized. It does not point anywhere. In the next line:

```
*x=10;
```

You are saying: Go to the memory that `x` points to and assign a `10` to that `int`. See the problem? There is no `int` where `x` points to, because `x` doesnt point anywhere. Your code has undefined behavior. Output could be anything.

If you want to assign `10` to an `int` you need an `int` first. For example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
int * fun(int * x)
{
    return  x;
}
int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    int * x = &y;
    *x=10;
    cout << fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This assigns `10` to `y`. The `cout` is still printing the value of `x`, which is the adress of `y`. It does not print the value of `y`. Not sure what you actually wanted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Makes sense.

Comment: Should'nt the compiler catch this? The code compiles but errors during run time.

Comment: @ShekarTippur yes it does, just pay attention to warnings https://godbolt.org/z/6qvaEodP8

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that in your program the pointer `x` is not pointing to any `int` variable. So first you have to **make sure** that the pointer `x` points to an `int` object as shown below.

You can **sovle** this as shown below:

```
    int i = 0;       //create the int object to which x will point 
    int *x = &i;     //make x point to variable i
    *x = 10;         //dereference the pointer x and assign 10 to the underlying variable i
    cout << *fun(x); //this prints 10
```